# display kmz with image on a google map with correct projection

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

I have a kmz file that contains an image that was lined up within Google Earth and then exported as a kmz file. The image lines up perfectly in Google Earth, but when the KMZ is displayed as an overlay in Google Maps the images are skewed and no longer line up properly with the base layer below. They seem to be rotated incorrectly.

It appears that this is a problem with the different projections used between Google Earth and Google Maps? Is there a work around when loading the overlay in Google Maps that would allow for this issue to be corrected?

KML snippet (from comments, so readable):

```
<name>TA_CustomMaps</name>
 <open>1</open> 
 <GroundOverlay> 
  <name>TA_3_33</name> 
  <color>82ffffff</color> 
  <Icon>     
    <href>files/TA_Sec3_33.jpg</href> 
    <viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>
  </Icon> 
  <LatLonBox>     
   <north>46.71319940900263</north> 
   <south>46.51856909608949</south> 
   <east>-114.4281143798832</east> 
   <west>-114.9183785328563</west> 
   <rotation>21.81811552052049</rotation>
 </LatLonBox> 
</GroundOverlay>
```

Comment: Can you provide more details or a kmz file that exhibits the problem?

Comment: It appears it is a problem with the rotation tag. I'm guessing that Google Maps does not support the rotation tag? Here is an excerpt from the kml contents from the original kmz file.
<name>TA_CustomMaps</name>
<open>1</open>
<GroundOverlay>
<name>TA_3_33</name>
<color>82ffffff</color>
<Icon>
<href>files/TA_Sec3_33.jpg</href>
<viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>
</Icon>
<LatLonBox>
<north>46.71319940900263</north>
<south>46.51856909608949</south>
<east>-114.4281143798832</east>
<west>-114.9183785328563</west>
<rotation>21.81811552052049</rotation></LatLonBox>
</GroundOverlay>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<rotation>` is not supported in [KML in Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps)

Comment: Is there a different approach that I could take. Since I know the angle I see that there is a jQuery plugin for rotating images, but the overlay images do not appear to have an id value to select them from. Is it possible to add an id to each overlay image?