# GeoReference tiff image into the Google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geospatial, gdal

I want to Geo-reference a tiff image contain a Map for a specific region, I need to add this region(image) and Geo-reference it on the Google map, SO I can see on the map for the region I select the image which I have inserted.

the image also need information such as the Latitude and Longitude of corners and size, and the pixel per meter measurement.

How to do the correct Geo-reference for that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps tool for accurately positioning image overlay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356543/google-maps-tool-for-accurately-positioning-image-overlay)

Answer (score 4):

There are different solutions to your problem, and the choice of the easiest solution will largely depend on your specific case, i.e. on how big your map is, how you want it to be included in Google Maps (as a complete image, or as tiles), and what the spatial reference system (coordinates) of your map are.

A relatively straightforward solution is to create an image overlay in Google Earth, to associate your image to this overlay and place it correctly using Google Earth imagery. You will be able to export this image overlay into a KMZ file which you might be able to load in GoogleMaps. However, in practice, this approach will probably not work properly due to the lack of support of image rotation in GoogleMaps (this issue is discussed in [display kmz with image on a google map with correct projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365814/display-kmz-with-image-on-a-google-map-with-correct-projection)).

If you know or can find out the bounding coordinates and pixel size for your image, you can use the GDAL tools as discussed in [Create geotiff from tiff and 4 corners latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956818/create-geotiff-from-tiff-and-4-corners-latitude-and-longitude).

If you don't know the bounding coordinates, you will most likely need to use a GIS software such as [QuantumGIS](http://qgis.org). In QuantumGIS you can use the GDAL georeference tool as described by Julien-Samuel Lacroix in his answer to your very same question on GIS StackExchange at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74964/georeference-tiff-image-into-the-google-map.

After getting your projection right (Google Maps use spatial reference system EPSG:3857), you'll be able to create a simple tiles overlay using the [GDAL2Tiles](http://www.klokan.cz/projects/gdal2tiles/) tool. An older version of this tool is also included in the GDAL utility programs and described at http://gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html.

You might also be interested into going through the step-by-step tutorial available at https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/raster.